# Where does the opening solo of the Rite of Spring come from?

Tags: classical-music, folk

In Tom Service's commentary to the [BBC Proms 2013 performance of the Rite of Spring](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rq1q6u3mLSM), he starts off with something I had no idea of:

> The best bassoon solo ever? It sounds otherworldly: but it's actually a Lithuanian wedding song… (TS) #riteofspring
>
> [@bbcproms on twitter](https://twitter.com/bbcproms/status/359019472788533248)

I'm really curious to listen to this Lithuanian wedding song. Is it known, or relatively easy to reach?

Comment: Cool- I'd never heard that, but multiple website articles verify that claim.  I'd recommend you go to such sites and track down the scholarly articles & published books they reference.   Or marry a Lithuanian :-)

Comment: I heard an interview with bass player Pino Palladino, who said that his bass line at the beginning of the Paul Young recording of 'Wherever I lay my hat' is based on that same Rite of Spring basson line.

Comment: @Brian That's a healthy dose of mind-blowingness for today. Thank you very much for that.

Comment: @E.P. yeah, I thought that was pretty awesome, too, so just had a listen to the track (first time in *many* years). Bit of a disappointment - only about 4 notes make it into the bass part for the intro...!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The song *Tu, manu seserėlė* was taken from Anton Juszkiewicz’s *Melodje ludowe litewskie*, (number 157 in the collection. You can see [a copy of the tune](http://www.idrs.org/publications/controlled/DR/JNL26/Myths.pdf).

In abc format:

```
X:157
T:Tu, manu seserėlė
C:Trad.
M:3/4
K:B
L:1/4
edB|G2d|1c2d:|2c2c|:edc|f2e|d2c|edB|G2d|c2c:|
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly the song is: "Tu, manu seserėlė" (from: http://www.orchestralbassoon.com/stravinsky-the-rite-of-spring/ (link now dead; archived version [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20150323082102/http://www.orchestralbassoon.com/stravinsky-the-rite-of-spring/))).

I can't figure out hot to link to the original tune but it's on the linked web page.